# issue with oracle spatial sdo_nn function

Tags: oracle, spatial

```
SELECT P.ID, P.LOC,P.GEOM.GET_WKT() WKT FROM MY_TEST P;

id     loc          wkt
----------------------------------------------
1   thalassery  POINT (75.489292 11.753003)
2   pilakool    POINT (75.495129 11.743255)
3   gopalapet   POINT (75.502338 11.736532)
4   mahe        POINT (75.536327 11.700562)
5   vadakara    POINT (75.598297 11.621928)
6   kannur      POINT (75.38475 11.873712)

 SELECT
     C.LOC loc1, 
     D.LOC loc2,
     SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(C.GEOM, D.GEOM, .005,'unit=km') AS SDO_DISTANCE
FROM MY_TEST C,
     MY_TEST D
ORDER BY 1, 2;  --which results 18.7476695068002 as the distance between id 1 and id 5
```

[image]

But I am getting different output on using sdo_nn function as:

```
SELECT 
     C.LOC,
     D.LOC,
     SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) AS SDO_NN_DISTANCE
FROM MY_TEST C,
     MY_TEST D
WHERE 
 sdo_nn(c.geom, d.geom,1)='TRUE'-- getting only 0 result sets on using 'UNIT=KM' parameter.
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[image]

THANKS FOR ANYHELP:)

Comment: You're getting different output because `SDO_NN_DISTANCE` uses metres (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_operat.htm#i80529) and your call to `SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE` uses kilometres.

Comment: @Luke Woodward, Thanks, you're correct, but how can i convert / display it into my required parameter, say 'unit= km',  if i  uses that parameter, it returns 0 in that field. for the given highlighted values, the result should be around 18.747...

Comment: If you want to convert a value in metres to a value in kilometres, divide by 1000.  If you are using some other unit, you'll have to do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the unit 'UNIT=KM':

```
SELECT 
     C.LOC,
     D.LOC,
     SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) AS SDO_NN_DISTANCE
FROM MY_TEST C,
     MY_TEST D
WHERE 
 sdo_nn(c.geom, d.geom,'UNIT=KM',1)='TRUE'
ORDER BY 1,2;
```